# Can't trigger Growl from the command line in iTerm2

Tags: growl, iterm2

In the article linked from the iTerm2 page, it says that this:

```
echo -e $'\e]9;Growl Notification\007'
```

should trigger a Growl notification but it doesn't.

I've goofed around a bunch but cannot make it work.

Growl notification is definitely enabled in preferences. I don't know that I've ever seen a Growl notification from iTerm2, so perhaps there's some broken linkage but I don't know how to debug that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I note that iTerm2 does not appear in the Growl application list, even though the iTerm2 preference for Growl is checked.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be present in Growl's Settings -> Applications in left sidebar.

I had to reinstall iterm. Then it appeared in this tab and notification started to work.